# Performance efficient way of setting pixels in GDI

Tags: c++, gdi

I've created a basic program that renders sprites in a windows console using the `SetPixel()` method, and it works fine, but there is massive overhead.
I've made some optimizations to this, which helped but it's still too slow.

Currently my program uses two buffers of `COLORREF` draws the newer to the screen, swaps them and starts over. However it only redraws a pixel if said pixel has changed. This improved performance massively but it's still slow.
Buffer swapping isn't done with pointers as of yet, but the real overhead is `SetPixel()` so, i'm looking for an alternative way of creating pixel level graphics with GDI, which is faster than `SetPixel()`
(ignore anim_frame and the first dimension of the img_data vector, they are just there for the future if i decide to add animated objects)

```
void graphics_context::update_screen()
{
update_buffer();

for (int x = 0; x < this->width; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < this->height; y++)
    {
        if (this->buffer.at(x).at(y) != this->buffer_past.at(x).at(y))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < this->scale_factor; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < this->scale_factor; j++)
                {
                    int posX = i + (this->scale_factor  * x) + this->width_offset;
                    int posY = j + (this->scale_factor  * y) + this->height_offset;

                    SetPixel(this->target_dc, posX, posY, this->buffer.at(x).at(y));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

buffer_past = buffer;
}
```

And this is the `update_buffer()` method:

```
void graphics_context::update_buffer()
{
for (int x = 0; x < this->width; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < this->height; y++)
    {
        buffer.at(x).at(y) = RGB(0, 0, 0);
    }
}

//this->layers.at(1)->sprite; <- pointer to member gfx_obj pointer

for (int i = 0; i < this->layers.size(); i++)
{
    gfx_object tmp_gfx = *this->layers.at(i)->sprite;

    for (int x = 0; x < tmp_gfx.img_data.at(0).size(); x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < tmp_gfx.img_data.at(tmp_gfx.anim_frame).at(0).size(); y++)
        {
            if(tmp_gfx.img_data.at(tmp_gfx.anim_frame).at(x).at(y) != RGB(0,255,0))
            buffer.at(x + this->layers.at(i)->locX).at(y + this->layers.at(i)->locY) = tmp_gfx.img_data.at(tmp_gfx.anim_frame).at(x).at(y);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `SetPixel` is notoriously slow, in part because it must discover the properties of the image being written to on every call. It's much faster to use `LockBits` and operate on the bitmap bytes directly, as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999814/locking-a-gdi-bitmap-in-native-c), but that's also more complicated because bitmap formats can differ.

Comment: If `target_dc` is a window device context, then you are making many GDI calls, it will be very slow. If `target_dc` is memory device context, then `SetPixel` is reasonably fast. Use `SetPixelV` which doesn't return the exiting color and is a bit faster. Either way is wrong. At the end you want to use `BitBlt` to draw the image. You can use `BitBlt` to draw the sprite as well.

Comment: `.at` isn't fast either, but that's likely secondary

Comment: @BarmakShemirani so i would have to switch to using bitmaps, to get reasonably efficient drawing?
And `target_dc` is a window device context

Comment: @MSalters is the `[]` operator faster? or should i access the memory directly with some pointer magic?

Comment: @kivi: yes, operator[] is the correct method. Pointer magic can be slower as the optimizer has to step back.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ideally you want to use `BitBlt` and draw on the screen once for each frame.

Otherwise you do multiple paint calls for each frame, and drawing is slow with flicker. For example:

```
case WM_PAINT: 
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    auto hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

    for (...)
        SetPixelV(hdc, ...) //<- slow with possible flicker

    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    return 0;
}
```

The main problem is not `SetPixel`, but the fact that we are making thousands of drawing requests to the graphics card, for each frame.

We can solve this by using a buffer in the form of "memory device context":

```
HDC hdesktop = GetDC(0);
memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdesktop);
hbitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdesktop, w, h);
SelectObject(memdc, hbitmap);
```

Now you can do all of your drawings on `memdc`. These drawings will be fast because they are not sent to the graphics card. Once you are finished drawing on `memdc`, you `BitBlt` the `memdc` on the actual `hdc` for target window device context:

```
//draw on memdc instead of drawing on hdc:
...

//draw memdc on to hdc:
BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, w, h, memdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
```

In practice you rarely need `SetPixel`. Usually you load a bitmap in to your background and sprite(s), and then draw everything on `memdc`, and `BitBlt` to `hdc`.

In Windows Vista and above you can use `BeginBufferedPaint` routine which might be a little more convenient. Example:

```
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif
#include <Windows.h>

class memory_dc
{
    HDC hdc;
    HBITMAP hbitmap;
    HBITMAP holdbitmap;
public:
    int w, h;

    memory_dc()
    {
        hdc = NULL;
        hbitmap = NULL;
    }

    ~memory_dc()
    {
        cleanup();
    }

    void cleanup()
    {
        if(hdc)
        {
            SelectObject(hdc, holdbitmap);
            DeleteObject(hbitmap);
            DeleteDC(hdc);
        }
    }

    void resize(int width, int height)
    {
        cleanup();
        w = width;
        h = height;
        HDC hdesktop = GetDC(0);
        hdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdesktop);
        hbitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdesktop, w, h);
        holdbitmap = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdc, hbitmap);
        ReleaseDC(0, hdc);
    }

    //handy operator to return HDC
    operator HDC() { return hdc; }
};

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    static memory_dc buffer;
    static memory_dc sprite;
    static memory_dc background;

    switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        RECT rc;
        GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);

        buffer.resize(rc.right, rc.bottom);
        background.resize(rc.right, rc.bottom);
        sprite.resize(20, 20);

        //draw the background
        rc = RECT{ 0, 0, sprite.w, sprite.h };
        FillRect(sprite, &rc, (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(GRAY_BRUSH));

        //draw the sprite
        rc = RECT{ 0, 0, background.w, background.h };
        FillRect(background, &rc, (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH));

        return 0;
    }

    case WM_PAINT: 
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        auto hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

        //draw the background on to buffer
        BitBlt(buffer, 0, 0, background.w, background.w, background, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

        //draw the sprite on top, at some location
        //or use TransparentBlt...
        POINT pt;
        GetCursorPos(&pt);
        ScreenToClient(hwnd, &pt);
        BitBlt(buffer, pt.x, pt.y, sprite.w, sprite.h, sprite, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

        //draw the buffer on to HDC
        BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, buffer.w, buffer.w, buffer, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        return 0;
    }

    case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
        InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, FALSE);
        return 0;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam);
}

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, LPTSTR, int)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex = { sizeof(WNDCLASSEX) };
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wcex.lpszClassName = L"classname";
    RegisterClassEx(&wcex);

    CreateWindow(wcex.lpszClassName, L"Test", WS_VISIBLE | WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 
        0, 0, 600, 400, 0, 0, hInstance, 0);

    MSG msg;
    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return (int)msg.wParam;
}
```

Note, this will be good enough for simple drawings. But GDI functions can't handle matrices etc. they have limited transparency support, so you might want to use a different technology like Direct2D which has better integration with the GPU

Comment: this worked like a charm, i got some reasonable results from it, and now i know that there is still plenty of overhead in my code elsewhere, which still need fixin'

Comment: Great. I updated `memory_dc` class so it has automatic clean up for GDI objects

Answer (score 2):

If you have full control over the pixels, use [SetDIBitsToDevice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-setdibitstodevice) or [StretchDIBits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-stretchdibits). You don't even need to create a memory device context.

Here is a 16x16 bitmap manually defined and displayed with StretchDIBits

[image: StretchDIBits]

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstdint>
const int CLIENT_WIDTH = 320;
const int CLIENT_HEIGHT = 240;
const int IMAGE_WIDTH = 16;
const int IMAGE_HEIGHT = 16;
const uint32_t bg = 0xffd800;
const uint32_t imageData [16*16] = {
bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg,
bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg,
bg, bg, bg,  0,  0,  0, bg, bg, bg, bg,  0,  0,  0, bg, bg, bg,
bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg,
bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg,
bg, bg, bg, bg,  0,  0, bg, bg, bg, bg,  0,  0, bg, bg, bg, bg,
bg, bg, bg, bg,  0,  0, bg, bg, bg, bg,  0,  0, bg, bg, bg, bg,
bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg,
bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg,
bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg,
bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg,
bg, bg, bg, bg,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, bg, bg, bg, bg,
bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg,
bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg,
bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg,
bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg, bg,
};

void drawImage(HDC hdc)
{
  BITMAPINFOHEADER bmih = {0};
  bmih.biSize     = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
  bmih.biWidth    = IMAGE_WIDTH;
  bmih.biHeight   = -IMAGE_HEIGHT;
  bmih.biPlanes   = 1;
  bmih.biBitCount = 32;
  bmih.biCompression  = BI_RGB ;
  bmih.biSizeImage    = 0;
  bmih.biXPelsPerMeter    =   10;
  bmih.biYPelsPerMeter    =   10;

  BITMAPINFO dbmi = {0};
  dbmi.bmiHeader = bmih;

  // Draw pixels without stretching
//  SetDIBitsToDevice(hdc, 0, 0, IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT,
//                    0, 0, 0, IMAGE_HEIGHT, imageData, &dbmi, 0 );

  StretchDIBits(hdc, 0, 0, CLIENT_WIDTH, CLIENT_HEIGHT,
                0, 0, IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT,
                imageData, &dbmi, 0, SRCCOPY);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
  switch(Message) {
    case WM_PAINT: {
      PAINTSTRUCT ps ;
      HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
      drawImage(hdc);
      EndPaint(hwnd, &ps) ;
      break;
    }
    case WM_DESTROY: { PostQuitMessage(0); break; }
    default: return DefWindowProc(hwnd, Message, wParam, lParam);
  }
  return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
  WNDCLASSEX wc = {0};
  HWND hwnd;
  MSG msg;
  wc.cbSize    = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
  wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
  wc.hInstance = hInstance;
  wc.lpszClassName = "GDIPixelsClass";
  wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH);
  RegisterClassEx(&wc);
  hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,wc.lpszClassName,"StretchDIBits",
                        WS_VISIBLE|WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 480, 320,
                        NULL,NULL,hInstance,NULL);
  DWORD dwStyle = (DWORD)GetWindowLongPtr( hwnd, GWL_STYLE ) ;
  DWORD dwExStyle = (DWORD)GetWindowLongPtr( hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE ) ;
  HMENU menu = GetMenu( hwnd ) ;
  RECT rc = { 0, 0, CLIENT_WIDTH, CLIENT_HEIGHT } ;
  AdjustWindowRectEx( &rc, dwStyle, menu ? TRUE : FALSE, dwExStyle );
  SetWindowPos( hwnd, NULL, 0, 0, rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top,
                SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOMOVE ) ;
  while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) {
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
  }
  return msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: *"You don't even need to create a memory device context."* - That's true, even though creating a (memory) DC is a relatively cheap operation. It's just a small structure initialized from constant data, which seems to surprise a lot of folks.