# Add more Red/Green/Blue to the screen pixels (C++)

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to make an app to **add more Red/Green/Blue to each pixel** of my screen.
Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tchar.h>

#include <windows.h>
#include <wingdi.h>
#include <winuser.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int screenWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
    int screenHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);

    HWND hwnd = GetDC(0);
    HDC hdc = GetWindowDC(hwnd);

    COLORREF pixel = GetPixel(hdc, 0, 0); // I want to get all of the pixels and modify their color
    HBRUSH brush = CreateSolidBrush(0x00FFFFFF);
    SelectObject(hdc, brush);
    PatBlt(hdc, 0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight, PATCOPY);

    ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
}
```

I want to modify the color of every pixel on the screen but doing:

```
COLORREF color = GetPixel(hdc, x, y);
color = color + std::atoi(argv[1]);
SetPixel(hdc, x, y, color);
```

Is too slow.
Is there a way to modify **all of the them at the same time**?

Comment: Look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53965792/15974438) answer.

Comment: Using Direct3D and a pixel shader would be the best.

Comment: What do you think happens after your program terminates and the windows next get repainted? Are you familiar with how painting works, i.e. `WM_PAINT` messages?

Comment: Why would it terminate?

Comment: @tortue678tortue678 It terminates when `main()` exits. Your code draws one time and then exits. Also, `HWND hwnd = GetDC(0); HDC hdc = GetWindowDC(hwnd);` is wrong. `GetDC()` returns an `HDC` not an `HWND`. Get rid of `GetWindowDC()` and use `HDC hdc = GetDC(0); ... ReleaseDC(0, hdc);` instead. Also, you need to restore the old `HBRUSH` via a 2nd call to `SelectObject()` before releasing the `HDC`: `HBRUSH oldBrush = (HBRUSH) SelectObject(hdc, brush); ... SelectObject(hdc, oldBrush);`

Comment: @tortue678tortue678 `(Get|Set)Pixel()` are indeed very slow. You could instead capture a screenshot of the screen into an in-memory bitmap first, then manipulate the raw pixel bits of that bitmap as needed, then `BitBlt()` the bitmap back to the screen.

Comment: Realistically though you can do all that code that @Remy listed, but your program isn't going to be effective. The screen isn't yours.

Comment: My question is: how do i manipulate the raw pixel bits @RemyLebeau

Comment: You can't. You can borrow them, and even temporarily overwrite them. But you cannot (easily) change the contents of the actual frame buffer. Though Windows probably has an interface that allows you to apply system-wide color correction.

Comment: @tortue678tortue678 you can't manipulate the raw pixel bits of the screen, that is why I said to copy the screen to an in-memory bitmap first. Then you can access the raw pixel bits of the bitmap, such as with [`GetDIBits()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getdibits)

Comment: Ok thank you! I'll try that

Comment: @RemyLebeau How do i copy the screen to an in-memory bitmap

Comment: @tortue678tortue678 `BitBlt()` from a screen `HDC` to a compatible `HDC` that has an `HBITMAP` selected into it. See [Capturing an Image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdi/capturing-an-image), just omit the `HWND` portion.