# Two questions about SetPixel() and multithreading

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

I'm trying to implement the Mandelbrot set with VS 2022 Community Edition. I do calculations and SetPixel() calls in a 2-D loop. It works, but takes 7 seconds to render the image. I want to speed things up. One approach is to break the image into blocks and dispatch the work to multiple threads. Before I go to that trouble, I need to know if SetPixel() is thread safe. I did some research and the answer is unclear. It seems to me that if two threads are working on different areas of the image, that concurrent calls to SetPixel() should be OK. Is it? What about using a mutex to control access to SetPixel()? The second approach seems to be LockBits... I see a lot of posts that say that SetPixel() is slow, and that LockBits should be used. Problem is that I can't find any support for LockBits in my system, and none of the posts completely answer the question of how to do that. Thank you. My code follows...

```
case WM_PAINT:
    {
    if (bHoldPaint) break;

        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

        RECT rect;
        GetClientRect(hWnd, &rect);

        // Algorithm obtained from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set.

        double x0, y0, x, y, xtemp;
        
        const int max_iterations = 1000;
        int iteration;
        
        int xPixel, yPixel;

        for (yPixel = rect.top; yPixel < rect.bottom; ++yPixel)
        {
            for (xPixel = rect.left; xPixel < rect.right; ++xPixel)
            {
                x0 = (xMax - xMin) / (rect.right - rect.left) * xPixel + xMin;
                y0 = (yMax - yMin) / (rect.bottom - rect.top) * yPixel + yMin;

                x = 0.0;
                y = 0.0;
                
                iteration = 0;
                
                while (x * x + y * y <= 2 * 2 && iteration < max_iterations)
                {
                    xtemp = x * x - y * y + x0;
                    y = 2 * x * y + y0;
                    x = xtemp;
                    ++iteration;
                }
                SetPixel(hdc, xPixel, yPixel, (COLORREF)(-16777215.0 / max_iterations * iteration + 16777215.0));
            }
        }

        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    }
    break;
```

Comment: p.s. I just noticed that I did not paste the entire code. The only thing missing is X/Y Max and X/Y Min. Just assume that they are constants.

Comment: It's not quite a dup, but `SetPixel()` is inherently slow when writing to the actual device, so [create an off-screen bitmap and write to that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53958727/1270789).

Comment: General rule of thumb: If a function's documentation doesn't call out and call out loud when it is thread safe, it almost certainly isn't.

Comment: Understood. That leads to the second half of my first question... Can I use a mutex to serialize the calls to SetPixel()?

Comment: I suspect not because that would require the other side that's using those pixels to know about and respect your mutex. Since that's buried deep in code you don't control...

Comment: "I can't find any support for LockBits in my system" what exactly does that mean?

Comment: Much better idea to use an off-screen bitmap and then draw the whole thing to the screen. Get that working without threading to start and then if you consider trying threads you can synchronize access to it since you're the only one using it.

Comment: user4581301: The other side of what's using those pixels is the display. I'm not using GetPixel(), for instance, to do further processing. This is just a simple algorithm that draws on the client window.

Comment: Blindy: What I mean is that I get no hits when I type the token "LockBits", and there seems to be no documentation. Is there a particular header/library that I need to include?

Comment: Exactly. The other side isn't your code you can add knowledge of the mutex to. Mutex is cooperative. Both sides must negotiate locking for a mutex to work. Eg: Thread A locks mutex, modifies `shared_string`, unlocks mutex. Thread B just modifies `shared_string` without checking and locking the mutex.  `shared_string`'s gonna get smashed because nothing ever tells A it's not safe to modify `shared_string` and obviously B never even checked.

Comment: user4581301: I'm not sure you understand what I meant by using a mutex. I would use a mutex to control access to SetPixel(). The threads that I would start would all vie for the mutex to use SetPixel(), releasing the mutex when their particular chuck of processing (say a line of pixels, or evan a single pixel) is done. Does that make sense?

Comment: You are correct, I misunderstood. I caution against this, though. Odds are very high that you will see no performance improvement and very possibly a degradation as the threads fight over access to the mutex and effectively become serialized once again plus the costs involved in dealing with the mutex. Strongly consider what the others have recommended and edit your own memory buffer. With that you can guarantee if a thread operates exclusively in its own zone you will never have collisions, never need a mutex, and only need one call to write the image to the screen when done.

Comment: user4581301: Thank you. I am not too familiar with bitmaps. Can you direct me, please, to the right starting points in the documentation? Several questions come to mind... First, I assume that a LockBit'ed memory block is raw memory, and I need to understand how it is laid out in terms of the device context. Second, I think that SetPixel() still works with the bitmap, but I might be better off by directly modifying the bitmap directly. (What's the tradeoff?) Third, I think the advantage of the bitmap is that I can draw on the screen without worrying about how to restore the underlying image.

Comment: Think about using function likes `SetDIBitsToDevice`?

Comment: fana: Thank you. I will investigate SetDIBitsToDevice.

Comment: Can you [`BitBlt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-bitblt) from the specified memory source device context into your destination device context?

Comment: YangXiaoPo-MSFT: Thank you. I don't know what that means. The only thing I know about BitBlt is what the documentation says, and that is a bunch of gobbleygook to me. I think that what people are trying to tell me is that I should write to a bitmap in memory, instead of using SetPixel(), and then select it into the DC for the window. Am I on the right track? If so, can you provide example code? Please, have a good day!

Comment: If you're realy on performance, you should use the GPU wich is inherently very multi threaded, like a compute shader (you can google on shader mandelbrot), for example  https://digitalerr0r.net/2010/12/13/fundamentals-of-fractals-5-the-mandelbrot-set/ but this is a whole new technical world.

Comment: SetPIxel is extremely inefficient,. Use an offscreen bitmap, which you can safely partition and write to from multiple threads at once. Then blit to the screen.

Answer (score 3):

A [device context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/device-contexts) can safely be used from multiple threads concurrently. Raymond Chen covered the details in the blog post [Thread affinity of user interface objects, part 2: Device contexts](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20051011-10/?p=33823):

> Device contexts (DCs) also have a certain degree of thread affinity. The thread that calls functions such as [`GetDC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdc) must also be the one that calls [`ReleaseDC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-releasedc), but [...] **during the lifetime of the DC, any thread can use it**.

The article moves on to explain that users are still required to coordinate access. This involves making sure that threads don't step on other threads' feet by overwriting the same areas. Coordination *could* be implemented via synchronization primitives (such as mutexes), but that is not strictly required. A far cheaper (and easier) way to accomplish the same thing is by structuring the code so that no two threads will ever write to the same pixel.

If you want to experiment with multiple threads updating the same DC you're all set. Doing that is well-specified. In this first iteration of performance optimization you should replace [`SetPixel()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-setpixel) with [`SetPixelV()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-setpixelv). The latter is faster as it doesn't *read* the previous color value (which you don't need anyway), but either one is incredibly expensive still.

---

Once you have made progress with that there are more options to evaluate:

- Update memory directly rather than having a costly GDI call go through the DC:
  To do this, allocate a block of memory of sufficient size, write to it, and construct a bitmap over that data when done (using [`CreateBitmap()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createbitmap), for example). `LockBits()` does pretty much that, but it is available in .NET's `System.Drawing.Bitmap` type only.
- Move the calculation out of the `WM_PAINT` message handler:
  Message handlers are called in order. While a program is busy handling a message, no other messages are getting dispatched (this is roughly correct enough). You can move the calculation off the UI thread and when it retires, signal to the UI that an update is necessary. A call to [`InvalidateRect()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-invalidaterect) is sufficient.
- Use a [thread pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/thread-pools) instead of launching individual threads:
  Spawning a thread is a relatively expensive operation in Windows. If you can reuse existing threads that have gone idle, it is a worthwhile optimization (or de-pessimization).
- Offload the calculation to a more appropriate processing unit:
  The specific workload here is incredibly well-suited for GPU calculation. The calculation of each pixel is independent of the results for any other pixel, making the problem [embarrassingly parallelizable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel). GPUs commonly have hundreds (or thousands) of processing units that execute code in parallel so going GPU will make a significant difference. (It's also fairly involved getting started.)

There are other things you can try out, but this will get you started. Almost, anyway. The first step forward is familiarizing yourself with [profiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)).

Comment: IInspectable: Thank you. This is all well and good, but I still don't have a good start on using bitmaps. Can you or someone please post an example of how to create a bitmap, write to it, and select it into the dc for the display.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75554618/1889329) uses a raw chunk of memory and illustrates how to call [`SetDIBitsToDevice()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-setdibitstodevice) to display the memory contents.

Comment: Though, I wouldn't recommend going there just yet. Instead, get the profiling covered first. If nothing else, that gets you a baseline reading of the performance you're going up against. You're in the comfortable position of having a working solution already, so capitalize on that. Invest time into making the collection of benchmarking results so convenient that you won't ever avoid doing so. Once that is in place, replace `SetPixel()` with `SetPixelV()` and see where that lands you. That may or may not change the performance characteristics, but you *will* have learned a lesson or two.

Comment: IInspectable: Thank you, again. I instrumented the loop with GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(). It takes 8 seconds with SetPpixel() in place, and 2 seconds without the SetPixel() call. That's a decent change that makes me want to try SetDIBitsToDevice(). I also tried SetPixelV(). I get the same performance - 8 seconds. As far as profiling goes, I'm not sure I see the need as the loop is very straightforward. I'll investigate SetDIBitsToDevice() and then look at threading - I have 12 logical processors in my laptop, so it seems that is the best bet. Please, have a good day.

Comment: IInspectable: I just checked on profiling in VS 2022 Community Edition. Apparantly, this is only supported in .NET and I am working in straight WinAPI. Oh well...

Comment: IInspectable: I have success! I implemented SetDIBitsToDevice() in place of SetPixel() and got the loop performance down from 8 seconds to 2 seconds. My next evolution will create 10 worker threads to process slices of the bitmap. I expect performance of around 0.2 seconds. Again, thank you very much for your support and advice. Please, have a good day.